# Getting just the lowest-level directory name for a file from split-path using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to get just the last part of the path name for a file.

Example:

```
c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt
```

I need to get `dir3` into a variable.

I have been trying with `Split-Path`, but it gives me the whole path.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This takes two invocations of `Split-Path` AFAICT:

```
PS> Split-Path (Split-Path c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt -Parent) -Leaf
dir3
```

Comment: thanks ! but in my case I had to specify -Leaf twice, also inside the brackets where you wrote -Parent, in my case I wanted the inner most folder name and my path did not contain any file name, just folders.

Comment: Thanks!  Mine was similar!  For me I used <(Split-Path "\\usa0xxxnas.na.xxx.net\xxxbackups\T_SQL_Web_Prod\" -leaf)> and it gave me T_SQL_Web_Prod directory.

Comment: Or equivalently, avoiding those pesky parentheses: `Split-Path c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf`

Answer (score 17):

This question is specifically asking for split-path it seems, but some other ways are:

If the file exists, I find it is much nicer to do:

```
(Get-Item c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt).Directory.Name
```

If the file does not exist, this won't work. Another way in that case is to use the .NET API, for example:

```
$path = [System.IO.Path];
$path::GetFileName($path::GetDirectoryName("c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep it simple and the path is going to be in normal form, you can use `String.Split()`:

```
"c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt".split("\")[-2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option using System.Uri:

```
PS> ([uri]"c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt").segments[-2].trim('/')
dir3
```

And if the file exists on disk:

```
PS> (dir c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt).directory.name
```

Comment: +1 I needed to get the path including only the first two directories in the original path and was able to do that based on your answer by using `([uri]"c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt").segments[1..3] -join ""` which returns `c:\dir1\dir2`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you want the name of the directory you are in I used this (thanks to Shay Levi for the original idea):

PS> (dir).directory.name[0]